# XSLT won't match empty XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have written a program in C# which converts one document schema to another using XSLT. 
The file to convert actually starts as SGML, which i first convert to XML ready to run the XSL stylesheet. The result of this conversion means that where i have elements like `<noclose>`in the SGML file (which is perfectly legitimate), after the pre-conversion to XML, they result in `<noclose></noclose>`. I.e empty elements.

It seems that when my XSL is run over the document, these empty elements are missed completely, despite having a template to match them:

```
<xsl:template match="noclose">
     <xsl:element name="newElement">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

This happens in a couple areas of the document which have empty XML elements as a result of the pre-conversion from SGML.
Does anyone know why the XSL template ignores the elements and how to get around it from an XSLT perspective please?

Comment: is there a typo in the question? you're asking about `<noclose>`, but your match is `noconds`...?

Comment: As per your `template`, it will create `newElement` whenever it finds node `noconds` (whether it is empty or not). Is it the requirement ? If you can provide minimal input and the xslt, it would be easier to answer

Comment: To rephrase @Vebbie's request: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes this was a typo sorry. Corrected. Yes the intention is to match using the template, and generate a 'newElement' XML element in its place. But this seems not to be the case when it sees these empty XML elements.

Comment: Template matches won't care if the element if empty or not (Not unless you had a condition matching "non-emptiness" in the match itself, which is not the case here). If the template is not being matched then it is not because it is empty. Either there is nothing selecting `noclose` in the XSLT, so that it never actually looks for a match in the first place. Or maybe `noclose` happens to be in a namespace. In either case, we would really need to see an example of the input XML, and more of your XSLT. Thank you!